# am start -a ACTIVITY from uiautomator code

Tags: android-uiautomator

I am trying to launch Settings app from am start -a ACTIVITY from uiautomator code,  in this way: am start -n com.android.settings/.Settings

But the problem is, the settings activity in one samsung device is /.Settings & in another device is /.SettingsTabActivity.

So, how can write the code that should launch Settings app in both the phones? (means how to handle both activities /.Settings & /.SettingsTabActivity)

Answer (score 1):

Get the device name from `getprop ro.build.product` and store to a string `devname`, Accordingly use the activity name.

```
if (devname.contains("samsung"))
    Runtime.getRuntime()
    .exec("am start -n com.android.settings/.Settings");
else
    Runtime.getRuntime()
   .exec("am start -n com.android.settings/.Settings$WifiSettingsActivity");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to start the main settings app then just use - am start com.android.settings this starts the package's main activity so should solve your problem.